# Running two emulators: one is always too slow

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am trying to run two AVDs side by side. The thing is that whichever AVD I open second, runs MUCH slower than the first one. It's not CPU or RAM, there is enough overhead.

Any ideas?

Comment: try using genymotion.

Comment: that's not really an answer to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase the memory that can be allocated to HAXM. When you install it you will notice a line in the final screen:

> Note: The memory reservation setting can be changed by running this installer again.

Navigate to `AndroidSDKDirectory/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager`

Run the installer (not the silent installer) and manually adjust the HAXM memory limit on this screen:

[image: HAXM memory adjuster]

At the time of this writing a stock Pixel (XL) emulator uses 1536 MB memory by default. So if you want to have enough memory available to HAXM to run 2 of these emulators, allocating ~4096 MB (a third more than necessary) is a safe bet.

Comment: when I run installer, button "modify" is disabled. (Version 6.2.1)

Answer (score 3):

I was also experiencing the same issue where the 2nd emulator was slow as molasses. I did some research on this and I think I have found a pretty decent solution. I am assuming that you have already installed Intel HAXM. If not, then please do so.
For best performances, it is advised that you allocate atleast half of the system RAM to Intel HAXM. This has been mentioned on the Intel HAXM page [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x) under the Tips & Tricks section. 
I allocated about 6 GB RAM to Intel HAXM and after that the performance of the 2nd emulator improved by a great deal. I would highly recommend you do the same. If you have already installed Intel HAXM, then please uninstall it and install it again with the amount of RAM as suggested on the above mentioned page.